# MS Access - Why am I getting blank forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I have the same 2003-MDB on two different workstations (both with 2007 installed).

On one workstation, forms with no data (it has an empty table is its data source) display with all the fields.

On the other workstation, the same form (with an empty table as its data source) displays blank, without any fields.

Why? Is there a system wide configuration option I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... the obvious answer found [here](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-20.html) was that this happens when both these conditions are met:

1. There are no records to display, and
2. No new records can be added.

There were several ways that were described in the for-mentioned web site, but I found another way. My MDB has several linked tables in several other MDBs, some on mapped drives (yes, this is bad on so many levels). Any way the table in question was empty and in an MDB on a mapped drive, that was not editable by the user on the second workstation (but it was editable by the user on the first one). This making the table read-only; and no new records could be added.